# Catching onRequestPermissionsResult() from outside the activity

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm currently trying to learn android and how to make android applications.
After many researchs I can't find a good way to handle permissions properly.

What I would like is to be able to ask permissions from any activity and detect if the user has accepted it or refused it.

Here's where I am:

I have a MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final Activity activity = this;
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   new PermissionHandler(activity).setPermissionListener(new PermissionHandler.PermissionAccordedListener() {
      @Override public void permissionAccorded() {
          // Permission Accorded 
      }
   }).askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

   //...
}
```

And a class PermissionHandler.java

```
public class PermissionHandler implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final int CODE = 12;

    public interface PermissionAccordedListener {
        void permissionAccorded();
    }

    public PermissionHandler setPermissionListener(PermissionAccordedListener permissionListener) {
        this.permissionAccorded = permissionListener;
        return this;
    }

    private PermissionAccordedListener permissionAccorded;

    public PermissionHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void askForPermission(String permission) {
        checkForPermission(activity, permission);

    }

    private void checkForPermission(Activity activity, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                    permission)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                        new String[]{permission},
                        CODE);
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                        new String[]{permission},
                        CODE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            if (permissionAccorded != null) {
                permissionAccorded.permissionAccorded();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (permissionAccorded != null) {
                        permissionAccorded.permissionAccorded();
                    }
                } else {
                    // permission denied! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }

}
```

It works quite great except that `onRequestPermissionsResult` is never triggered.

So first of all, is that the good approach? 
If yes, what am I doing wrong?
And if no, are there any resources out there for this kind of stuff?

Comment: You have to override onRequestPermissionsResult() from your Activity and just call your PermissionHandler's onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

Comment: So if I have multiple activity which require permissions I would have to add the `onRequestPermissionsResult`on every activity ?

Comment: Yes unfortunately.
I recommand you to use a library like EasyPermissions https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
It reduces your code a lot but you will still need to call EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults) yourself from your calling Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dexter library which handle permissions also can handle Multiple permissions
see documentation for more details
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter